# Implementing Actionlistener in an RTP GUI

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, java-2d, ready

So I was trying to create two buttons for an interface, I've tried implementing ActionListener to enable one of the buttons to print a string but it gave me an error which said that "actionlistener wasn't implemented in the class BorderDemo"

What have I done wrong?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
class BorderDemo
implements ActionListener
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
JFrame F = new JFrame("Buttons");
F.addWindowListener
(new WindowAdapter()
{
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
{
System.exit(0);
}});
F.setSize(544,416);
JPanel pane = (JPanel) F.getContentPane();
pane.add(new Picture(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
pane.add(new JButton("Start"),BorderLayout.WEST);
pane.addActionListener(this);
pane.add(new JButton("Stop"),BorderLayout.EAST);
F.setVisible(true);
F.setResizable(false);
}
}
class Picture extends JComponent
{
public Picture ()
{
repaint();
}

public void paint (Graphics g)
{
g.setColor(Color.yellow);
g.fillOval(getWidth()/4,getHeight()/4,
getWidth()/2,getHeight()/3);
g.setColor(Color.black);
g.fillOval(getWidth()/2,getHeight()/4,
getWidth()/17,getHeight()/3);
g.setColor(Color.black);
g.fillOval(getWidth()/3,getHeight()/4,
getWidth()/17,getHeight()/3);
g.setColor(Color.white);
g.fillOval(getWidth()/5,getHeight()/5,
getWidth()/5,getHeight()/7);
g.setColor(Color.white);
g.fillOval(getWidth()/3,getHeight()/8,
getWidth()/5,getHeight()/7);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Item clicked: "+e.getActionCommand());
}
}
```

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `actionPerformed` is added to `Picture` class instead of `BorderDemo`. So if you move it into `BorderDemo` it should solve the mentioned error.

The cause for the error is the fact that `BorderDemo` is declared as implementing `ActionListener` interface:

```
class BorderDemo implements ActionListener
```

However, it does not implement it. Add `actionPerformed` method defined in `ActionListener`, ie:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
}
```

Take a look at [Implementing an Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html) tutorial. Also see [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).

Some minor comments:

1. You would probably want to add action listeners to buttons, rather than `JPanel`.   `JPanel` does not accept action listeners.
2. Instead of adding window listener to the frame to exit the application on closing you can use:

   `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`
3. Instead of setting frame size with `setSize(544, 416);` implement `getPrefferedSize()` in `Picture` and call `pack();` on the frame.
4. In `Picture` class, don't override `paint()`, override `paintComponent()`. Also, don't forget to call `super.paintComponent()` in your implementation. See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).
5. Be sure to create UI component on *Event Dispatch Thread* using `invokeLater()`. See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
6. As already mentioned in comments above, code readability is very important. See [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) for details and examples.

***EDIT: example based on posted code that runs OK in RTP 1.7***

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


class BorderDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Buttons");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Start clicked");
            }
        });
        JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
        stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Stop clicked");
            }
        });

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(new Picture(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(startButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        contentPane.add(stopButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }

    static class Picture extends JComponent {
        public Picture() {
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(544, 416);
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.fillOval(getWidth() / 4, getHeight() / 4, getWidth() / 2,
                    getHeight() / 3);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillOval(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 4, getWidth() / 17,
                    getHeight() / 3);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillOval(getWidth() / 3, getHeight() / 4, getWidth() / 17,
                    getHeight() / 3);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillOval(getWidth() / 5, getHeight() / 5, getWidth() / 5,
                    getHeight() / 7);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillOval(getWidth() / 3, getHeight() / 8, getWidth() / 5,
                    getHeight() / 7);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however I do have further question: Are all of the codes you're suggesting available in Ready To Program? (Version 1.7)

Comment: @LongVuTa Is RTP bound to a particular version of Java?

Comment: @LongVuTa seems that RTP 1.7 uses Java 1.4, so you should be able to implement all suggestions. See an edit for an example.